# How to identify and highlight features programmatically?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS there is an option to select features of a selected layer using a "identify feature" tool. Then the feature get highlighted in a different color and attribute dialog is poping up.
like that i want to highlight the multiple features programatically.

Ex: I have a set of vector layers which consists of number of roads as features. I need to select few roads by looking at its attributes and highlight.

Is there any way of achieving this using python code?

Comment: hi guys, can we achieve this through a qgis python plugin?

Answer (score 14):

After few days of playing with QGIS, finally found a solution. There is a method in QgsVectorLayer class called setSelectedFeatures (const QgsFeatureIds &ids).

```
selection=[]

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry()
    roadNo = feature.attribute("Road_no")
    if roadNo == row[0].strip():
      selection.append(feature.id())
 ----
 ----
 layer.setSelectedFeatures(selection)
```

Hope this helps,